# Get image Width and Height with VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

In VB.net I need to read through a folder full of images and get their: File name, Height in pixels and Width in pixels and assign their values to individual variables.

thanks.

Mike.

Comment: Have you tried anything?  You're not likely to get helpful response if you don't least show some effort on your part.

Comment: i dont honestly know where to start, ive never worked with images in vb.net, if someone could point me in the direction of where to look for decent info ill get my learn on.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Drawing
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim s As New DirectoryInfo("C:/Files")
        Dim files As FileInfo() = s.GetFiles("*.jpg")
        For Each f As FileInfo In files
            Dim bmp As New Bitmap(f.FullName)
            Console.WriteLine("Width: " & bmp.Width.ToString() + " > Height: " & bmp.Height.ToString())
        Next
        Console.Read()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: thanks for that. i can now start on working out how it all works!

Comment: What about if we have the string variable of the full path name?

Comment: @JimThio, You mean as in an URI path?

Comment: URI? What is URI? I think the path to the computer. Like c:\helloworld.png

Comment: @JimThio, I see what you mean now. You mean if you do not want to search in a directory. The Bitmap has a constructor that takes an Absolute Path. So you can skip the for loop, and just pass the path to the Bitmap constructor like this: `Bitmap bmp2 = new Bitmap("c:\\helloworld.png");`

Comment: Don't forget to dispose the bitmap when you're done: bmp.Dispose()