# Increase row size depend upon the images in DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` like this

I am populating my `DataGridView` like this:

```
Dim cd As SqlCommandBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(adapter)
adapter = New SqlDataAdapter("select c.cid,c.CompanyName,d.dtId,d.dtName as Department,d.dtPhone as Phone,d.dtEmail as Email,d.empimage from CompanyMaster_tbl c join  DepartmentMaster_tbl d on c.Cid=d.cId order by cid", con.connect)

dt1 = New DataTable
bSource = New BindingSource
adapter.Fill(dt1) 'Filling dt with the information from the DB
bSource.DataSource = dt1
gv.DataSource = bSource
gv.Columns("cid").Visible = False
gv.Columns("dtId").Visible = False
Dim img As New DataGridViewImageColumn
img.HeaderText = "Image"
gv.Columns.Insert(6, img)

For i As Integer = 0 To gv.Rows.Count - 1
    gv.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value = gv.Rows(i).Cells(7).Value
Next
gv.Columns("empimage").Visible = False
```

If `DataGridView` have image in `ImageColumn` I want to increase my row width and image should stretch in that column. What changes I have to make in my code?

I wanted to post my `DataGridView` image for your better understanding, but I need at least 10 reputation to post images.

Comment: You post your image on another site and link it here.

Comment: Use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14991802/get-image-width-and-height-with-vb-net to detect image width then set column width accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

use
`gv.AutoSizeRowsMode` and `gv.AutoSizeColumnsMode`